# Installing web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I know there are a lot of discussions over this question of installing web.py. I have checked most of them and did

```
pip install web.py
easy_install web.py
python setup.py
```

install after downloading and copying the files in the python34 folder.
But still not working.
First case:

```
>>> pip install web.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install web.py
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Second Case:

```
>>> easy_install web.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    easy_install web.py
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Third Case:

```
 python setup.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python setup.py
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

pip and easy_install are command line programs, not python functions. So to get them to work, type into the terminal of your choice `pip install web.py`

Comment: in command prompt from which directory should I run this command?

Comment: In the directory where the file `web.py` is.

Answer (score 1):

After download web.py source file, you don't need to copy it to python34 dir. Just put it somewhere you lik. In the folder where `setup.py` is located, use:

```
python setup.py install
```

to install it.

Or simply in the terminal use:

```
pip install web.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways here is the complete [installation guide](http://webpy.org/install#install) for web.py. By the way are you using `pip` in `sudo`mode?